# Узнать время в нужном мне часовом поясе

Tags: java, android, дата

Как можно узнать текущее время в нужном мне часовом поясе? А точнее UTC-0?

Comment: А откуда вы берете время и в каком виде? Если вы используете ```System.currentTimeMillis()```, то она возвращает ```Unix time```, который сам по себе в UTC-0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такой пример сделал, чтоб можно было потестить:

```
TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00"));
time.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Здесь "GMT+00" это как UTC в данном контексте. К примеру если хотите поставить UTC+3, то:

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+03"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone, чтобы перевести твою дату в нужный часовой пояс. Например так..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.UTC_TIME, "UTC"));
Date dateInUtc = sdf.parse(myOriginalDate);
```

Comment: С эти все понятно. А как выбрать именно UTC-0?

Comment: @Andrach, `UTC-0` не существует. `UTC` - Это и есть 0, время по Гринвичу, `GMT +0`