# Неверное начальное значение таймера

Tags: java, android

Пыталась сделать таймер по [примеру](http://rusdelphi.com/help/krasivyj-tajmer-dlya-android/). Но почему-то всё время начальное значение неверное - вместо 00:00:01 после старта получаю значение 03:00:01, в остальном вроде таймер работает нормально - изменения по секундам есть. При проверке оказалось, что

```
String temp = (new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss")).format(new Date(1));
```

возвращает значение

> 03:00:00

. Вывод такой же даже с учётом часового пояса:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Minsk"));
String temp = dateFormat.format(new Date(1));
```

Почему? Разве вывод не должен быть 00:00:01?

Comment: Часовой пояс учитывается?

Comment: @qzavyer, даже с учётом часового пояса вывод такой же

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481040/191270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в часовом поясе. Чтобы получить 00:00:01 попробуйте следующий код:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1000)));
```